# AG-GRID - cell editing stops while clicking anywhere inside the ag-grid table

Tags: javascript, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

While editing a particular cell, clicking anywhere outside the cell and inside the ag-grid table takes us out of the editing mode. Any suggestions on how to suppress that.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not strictly possible. Clicking outside the cell will stop editing, see the documentation [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/#stop-end-editing).

Comment: Apparently, I came across a way to stop that by explicitly imposing class     
```{pointer-events: none}```
But now I have a different problem where while editing(using the edit method), I am not able to give to click on Edit input. I tried putting the following class to the input box but failed.    

```{pointer-events: all}```